# Getting the version of Livy on the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, livy

how to get what is the version of the livy I am using in the cluster? we have both livy client and server on cluster nodes but I need to know what is its version preferably on a horthonwork cluster.

Answer (score 2):

on a node with livy installed:
run
`ls -l /usr/hdp/current/livy2-server/jars/livy-{server,client}*`

**output:**

```
/usr/hdp/current/livy2-server/jars/livy-client-common-0.4.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar
/usr/hdp/current/livy2-server/jars/livy-server-0.4.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar
```

this is version 0.4.0 apparently (on a cluster running HDP 2.6.3.0).
not the most elegant way - but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually go to the livy installation directory and check the livy.jar version.

I am on an EMR and the path for jars is  **/usr/lib/livy/jars/**. So I tried :

```
[root@host jars]# ls /usr/lib/livy/jars/ | grep livy

livy-api-0.7.0-incubating.jar
livy-client-common-0.7.0-incubating.jar
livy-core_2.11-0.7.0-incubating.jar
livy-rsc-0.7.0-incubating.jar
livy-server-0.7.0-incubating.jar
```